# why contend show multiple time in angular while using ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I have two problem in my demo .I am making a pop over .I should open on icon click(here is used star icon).when i click star icon I am able to see pop up screen as I want but problem is that when I click another icon /star icon it open another pop over without closing the first one pop over.I need to display pop over one at time..

- 1 ) can we show pop over one at one time .it show only one pop over
  at one time.

  2)when I include in my plunker (tooltip.js and pop over plugin).It show the contend on **mouseover** event .but when i remove this it show on **click** event why ?

Here is plunker with scripts  tooltip and popover .display on click ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/OYiawflIBnpJ1PKx02LG?p=preview

here is the plunker with these plugin display on mouser over event why ?
http://plnkr.co/edit/OYiawflIBnpJ1PKx02LG?p=preview

```
 <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/a98aey2mlu0h511/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
 <script src=" https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/s1imyubboz1qjtl/bootstrap-popover.js?m="></script>
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, both plunkers are the same.  I recommend using bootply.com for this kinds stuff.

Comment: ok but can you please solve first problem..open this http://plnkr.co/edit/OYiawflIBnpJ1PKx02LG?p=preview click any one of star icon .and click again it show 2 at a time

Comment: @RobSchmuecker do you have any idea ?

Comment: Yes I will look into it.  Just busy!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker please anser this Question whenever you get time .I am just frustrated from night

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are still working on the problem, following is the solution. Though I am not sure if this is the best way to do it as I'm starting with `AngularJS`.

```
var getTemplate = function(contentType, scope, element) {

    var template = $templateCache.get("templateId.html");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'pop.html',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
          var options = {
            content: data,
            placement: "right",
            html: true,
            date: scope.date,
        };
    $(element).popover(options);

    //FIND ALL POPOVERS AND HIDE THEM EXCEPT CURRENT ONE//
    $(element).on("show.bs.popover",function(t,e){
      $("span[mypopover]").not(this).popover('hide');
    });

  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
    });

    return template;
};
```

Following are the lines:

```
$(element).on("show.bs.popover",function(t,e){
    $("span[mypopover]").not(this).popover('hide');
});
```

Plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/WM0K8sdPVHSNeuIlLBim

Comment: can you share plunker