# is all bootstrap javascript plugin integrate in one js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I just started learning bootstrap .I study the documentation of bersion 2.0.3 that i need to add bootstrap.js, bootstrap.css , if I need to implement anything I need to enter jquery and plugin from here.
http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/javascript.html

But When I goes uper version 3.2 or 2.3.2
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

there is that line return
**Plugins can be included individually (though some have required dependencies), or all at once. Both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js contain all plugins in a single file.**

what does it mean ?
if I include bootstrap.js .it will contain all plugin ? No need to add other plugin ?

Comment: Yes no need to include anything else.  Using the individual parts is only for optimising your site and by virtue of this question I don't think that's an issue for you right now.

Comment: Bootstrap.js is the `unminified` human-readable version which is easier for `debugging` and the `.min.js` is just smaller making your page download quicker.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker from while version it is startted ?

Comment: Either version, they are both the same thing, one version of the file is just a compressed version of the other.  In both bootstrap 3 and v2.3.2 you just need the 1 file (either bootstrap.min.js or bootstrap.js doesn't matter which one but use only one)

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I know that bootsrap .is unminfied.the Question is if I include unminfied .if there requirement to meed add plugin files(popover , tooltop plugins)available in this http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/javascript.html

Comment: No, just stick to the later versions, you referenced 2.0.3 which is over 2 years old!

Comment: Thanks man ..if you have time please look at this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149978/why-contend-show-multiple-time-in-angular-while-using-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you include bootstrap.js you don't need to include bootstrap.min.js.  If you wish to use these other plugins you will need to include their specific *.js file.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.3.2 you can use bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css only and they have all the plugins. The customizer allows you to download a lighter version without the plugins you don't need so you get a gain in the performance of your application.